Android Studio won't recognize my current jdk version
I continue to get a "enhance switch block is not supported by language '8'" message even after upgrading to Java 22. Searches for solutions only lead to fixes for much older versions of Android Studio that don't match my settings (I'm using 2024 Koala). Is it a problem with a missing or incorrect PATH?
I've tried manually installing the newest jdk, not the newest java download on Oracle, but no luck.

invalidate caches & restart - assumed you did set the jdk properly and set the correct compiler level (jdk22) and still not working properly

Did you set the project's language level?
